# バフェットコードのAPIの仕様はどこにありますか。

Tags: json, api

こちらの記事をみてバフェットコードにWeb API機能があることを知りました。

https://blog.buffett-code.com/entry/how_to_use_api

このAPIの細かい仕様はどこを参照すればよいでしょうか。

Comment: 2件の質問しか存在しない特定サイトのためにタグを作成するべきではないと思われ、タグを削除しました。良いサイトですが。

Comment: 英語版でも [同じ投稿](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57941564) をされていますが、オフトピックという判断のようです。

Answer (score 1):

以下のサイトに細かい仕様が公開されています。
基本的にレスポンスは仕様に則ったJSON形式で返されます。

http://docs.buffett-code.com/